# unable to add latlng from api to react-google-map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-google-maps

passing as props  here

<MyMapComponent
isMarkerShown
googleMapURL={`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places`}
loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
containerElement={<div style={{ height: `400px` }} />}
mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
lat={lat}
lang={long}

```
                  />
```

Map component

```
        import React from 'react'
        import { withScriptjs, withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, Marker } from "react-google-maps"
        
        const MyMapComponent = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap((props) => {
            return (
                < GoogleMap
                    defaultZoom={5}
                    defaultCenter={{ lat: props.lat, lng: props.lang }}
                >
        
                    {props.isMarkerShown && <Marker position={{ lat: props.;at, lng: props.lang }} />}
                </GoogleMap >
            )
        }));
        
        export default MyMapComponent;
```

Comment: Can you please add a description of your issue and what you are seeing? Also, can you provide an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) of your code? You can use [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.